# Foreign key constraint fails in an empty table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a new project running, where there are 2 tables `groups` and `members`. They are both empty at the time and there is a foreing key constraint on members table `group_id`.

Now I start off by creating a group which may later have many members, however, as I try to create it, I receive the following message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cogro`.`groups`, CONSTRAINT `groups_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `members` (`group_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Your foreign key references `members` which is the parent table.So to insert a value into `groups` table it first have to exists in the members table in the respective column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have entered wrong direction of the foreign key. Currently `groups.id` references `members.group_id` (in order to have an entry in `groups` with `id = 1` you should have an entry in `members` with `group_id = 1`)

Change the defintion to:

```
CONSTRAINT `members_group_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)
```